# Generate all non-isomorphic signed graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A *signed graph* is a graph in which each edge has a plus or minus sign. More specifically, a signed graph is a couple $S=(G, s)$, where $G=(V, E)$ is a graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$, and $s$ is a function that assigns $(+)$ or $(-)$ to any $e \in E$.

Two signed graphs $S_1=\left(G_1, s_1\right)$ and $S_2=\left(G_2, s_2\right)$ are *isomorphic* if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic through a mapping under which signs of edges are preserved.

We know that `geng` in `nauty` can generate non-isomorphic simple graphs, but is there a tool (or algorithm) for generating signed graphs?

It's interesting that I found the corresponding sequence on OEIS ([A004102.](https://oeis.org/A004102)) It states that a signed graph is equivalent to a 2-multigraph.

It gives me a list:

```
0       1
1       1
2       3
3       10
4       66
5       792
6       25506
7       2302938
8       591901884
9       420784762014
10      819833163057369
11      4382639993148435207
12      64588133532185722290294
13      2638572375815762804156666529
14      300400208094064113266621946833097
15      95776892467035669509813163910815022152
```

For example, the following is all signed graphs with three vertices.

[image]

However, I haven't come across a corresponding tool yet.

In addition, for connected signed graphs, I haven't seen any information regarding the associated counting.

Comment: There's an obvious "brute force" type algorithm (generate all labeled signed graphs, check for isomorphisms and throw out duplicates) which would be a simple exercise to program, so I think you should clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @SamHopkins Indeed, the first approach that came to my mind was brute force. I'm a bit concerned that such brute force could generate an overwhelming number of graphs. Specifically, I want to generate all signed graphs with 7 vertices and then find ones that meet some conditions.

Comment: Fortunately, just Brendan told me `nauty` can do this by using `multig `function, with edges having a minus sign 
represented by a double edge.